# event after list finish rendering?

Tags: apache-flex

I'm using a spark list to render data which I get from a web service.
is there an event which fires after the list has finished rendering all the data ?
I want to show a loading image to the user until the list finishes.

Thanks

Comment: The list rendering is almost instant. What you should track is the time between the webservice call and the webservice result and then show the loading progress on that consideration.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the event you are looking for is updateComplete.

Comment: Thanks Ariel.it's exactly what I needed

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I'd create 2 states: "loading" and "normal".  The initial state is "loading" by setting currentState by default, during which it shows a loader.  After that, I would have a check on the `data` property that you surely have somewhere.  You can bind that to check if it's not null and change the state accordingly.  Here's an example:

```
<s:Group currentState="{someDataFromService?'normal':'loading'}">
   <s:states>
      <s:State name="normal" />
      <s:State name="loading" />
   </s:states>
   <custom:SomeLoadingComponent includeIn="loading" />
   <s:List id="list" dataProvider="{someDataFromService}" enabled.loading="false" />
</s:Group>
```

I left out the data property since I'm sure you can figure that part out on your own.